# which command equivalent in Python

Tags: python, command

I have the following code which i am using to check if the program class-dump exists on a system. The program only returns a blank.

```
cmd = ["which","class-dump"]
process =  subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print process.stdout.read()
```

This code always returns a blank. Technically it should work right ?

Comment: Does `which class-dump` produce a non-empty output on the command line?

Comment: No it returns the path where class-dump is. I want to get the path through the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, it looks like the class-dump does not exists (in the PATH used by your python interpreter)

Comment: I dont get it. The subprocess call should actually call the command exactly how it does in the terminal right ? It works fine in the terminal but keeps returning blank when run from python.

Comment: @Amritha : the path where `which` is looking is the content of the "current" PATH, in your case, the PATH in your shell may be correct, but not the PATH variable used in your python interpreter. As Tempos said, dump your os.environ["PATH"] to confirm

Comment: Ok yeah i understood the error now. The shell is pointing to a different path and class-dump is not there. How do I change the environ path ? Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

I tried the following on my machine and its working perfectly.

```
import subprocess
cmd = ["which","java"]
process =  subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print process.communicate()
```

this is the output

```
('/usr/bin/java\n', None)
```

Answer (score 1):

`which` is a shell built-in. You need to pass `shell=True` to the Popen.

Comment: Still prints blank even if shell = True is added

Comment: @rplnt : `which` is an alias to a real file (/usr/bin/which), if python wasn't able to find the which executable, it would raise an exception.

Comment: @Cédric Thanks for correction. Wasn't sure about that and doesn't have any *nix machine in front of me at the moment. So I just searched for list of built-ins and which was there.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you use `communicate` instead? See this warning:

> Warning
>
> Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or
>   .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe
>   buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

Also, is it possible that your script runs under another `PATH` than your shell? Dump `os.environ["PATH"]` and check.

Comment: This warning is substantial only if both directions are used. I would suspect the `PATH` stuff...

Comment: Ok yeah i understood the error now. The shell is pointing to a different path and class-dump is not there. How do I change the environ path ? Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

This code does the same thing as the shell `which` command programatically, except that it does not "find" symbolic links.  To support that, you can enhance the `isx` function.

```
import os.path, itertools
isx = lambda program: lambda folder: (lambda p: \
    os.access(p, os.X_OK) and os.path.isfile(p))(os.path.join(folder, program))

def which(program):
  try:
    return itertools.ifilter(isx(program), os.environ['PATH'].split(':')).next()
  except StopIteration:
    raise ValueError, 'no executable file named %s found in search path' % (program,)
```

Example use:

```
>>> which('ls')
'/bin'
>>> which('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in which
ValueError: no executable file named foo found in search path
```